# Trying to upload multiple files, but getting str error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload multiple files but I get this error:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

The thing is related to my `__str__` function. If I leave it like `return self.file`, then it will just show an object, not the real filename. I have also, tried using `os.basename` but it wasn't successful either.

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

class AnotherClas(models.Model):
    file_upload = models.ForeignKey('FileUpload', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Comment: Got this error: __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: When asking about an error on Stack Overflow, please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/147XHVN.txt

Comment: The traceback says the error is coming from `/admin/courses/lecture/add/`. Are you sure that the error is coming from your `FileUpload.__str__` method, and not `Lecture.__str__`?

Comment: You were right. I converted the lecture __str__ to return a str of itself and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

you can also return unicode version for filename

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file
```

Comment: Second method is deprecated for Python 3.

Comment: well, i was assuming 2.7. in that case converting the filename to string should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in lecture class actually, had to convert the return a  **str** as well, not only in the inherited class.